# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unexpected char 0x1d at 4 in signature value:

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I'm using retrofit for calling my services. One of my services has a header parameter that it signed by SHA256-RSA, but when I invoke my request, I've got the error like this :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unexpected char 0x1d at 4 in signature value: "|._趿s<�ˠ"
```

my request method is :

```
Call<ResponseBody> getToken(@Header("Signature") String Signature,@Header("signature") String signature,@Header("headers") String headers, @Field("username") String username, @Field("password") String password, @Field("grant_type") String grantType);
```

and my signing method is :

```
 String pkcs8Pem = pkcs8Lines.toString();
        pkcs8Pem = pkcs8Pem.replace("-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----", "");
        pkcs8Pem = pkcs8Pem.replace("-----END PRIVATE KEY-----", "");
        pkcs8Pem = pkcs8Pem.replaceAll("\\s+", "");

        // Base64 decode the result

        byte[] pkcs8EncodedBytes = Base64.decode(pkcs8Pem, Base64.DEFAULT);

        // extract the private key

        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(pkcs8EncodedBytes);
        KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        PrivateKey privKey = kf.generatePrivate(keySpec);

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, privKey);
        Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
        signature.initSign(privKey);
        signature.update(message.getBytes());
        return signature.sign();
```

could you help with that?

Answer (score 0):

there are several characters, that could cause this error, for example an unvisible newline character, as stated in this github issue:

https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1153

This is forbidden by okhttp Client, which is utilized by retrofit to make http calls.
I would recommend you log the lower case signaturer esult and check directly which character is causing the trouble.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

This can be only solved with retrofit starting with version `2.10.0` which is currently only available as a SNAPSHOT version (Pull-Request: https://github.com/square/retrofit/pull/3661).

With version 2.10.0 you can simply allow unsafe non-ascii values for your header:

```
@Header("Signature", allowUnsafeNonAsciiValues = true)
```

In order to use the SNAPSHPT version, you need to add sonatype as additional source in your root build.gradle:

```
repositories {
    ...
    
    maven {
        url "https://s01.oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
    }
}
```

Furthermore you need to use a snapshot version in yout module level build.gradle:

```
dependencies {    
   ...

   // as of today this is the latest SNAPSHOT version..
   implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.10.0-20230517.223446-56"
}
```